# Shared Excel doc with one user who's changes aren't saving for others to see

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

So my office uses tick sheets to catalogue tasks performed throughout the day in order to input them into the time-card/work-volume prediction system at the end of the day. A few years ago, when this was becoming quite laborious to do from hand written sheets, a colleague and I set up a shared Excel workbook where up to 20 colleagues per workbook could put their information into their individual tab, and it would all pull through into one condensed page that was easy to print and input into the system at the end of the day. The sheet was built using Excel 2007 on a Windows XP machine.

My office has recently gone through an upgrade to Windows 7 and MS Office to 2010. Everyone on the team but one person, we'll call them K, has been able to continue using the sheet without incident. K inputs their data and saves, but when anyone else opens the file K's tab is blank and the data doesn't pull through. But when K opens the sheet again their data is still there, and they can see the data others have put in.

I sat with K while they were inputting their information yesterday, and I didn't see any user errors that might account for this. I've tried Google for a solution, but I haven't found anything quite like this situation yet. Any thoughts on what might be causing this, which I can look into?

Comment: I'm really at a loss as to how you ever got this to work. Excel doesn't allow multiple people in the same file at the same time. If you upgraded to Office 365 or Office 2016, there are options to get this to work. But, what you are doing sounds completely unsupported. Anytime someone else saves the file it is going to overwrite everyone else's changes. I have to be missing something here, how did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Office 2016 replaced and improved the old sharing feature (which has its pitfalls as well as its uses) which was available starting with Excel on Win98. I've been using the feature in various settings since around 2000. And 2010 is the newest version available in my company of 50,000+, so upgrade decisions beyond that are well out of my purview.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently it had to do with the file type that was being used. I moved teams last year, and the person who has been setting up the weekly sheet for the last couple of months has been saving it in the old .xls format. I got them to set the sheet up in .xlsx (which is what it was built in) and K's changes are displaying the same as everyone else's now. I don't know *why* the file type caused only one person's changes not to display properly, but I'm going to have to assume it has to do with the decreased functionality of that file type.